# Take output of bash command and pass it as command line argument to a c executable (pipes)

Tags: c, shell, redirect, pipe, output

I am trying to make a custom shell in c and when i run

pwd | ./show

it will take the pwd output and pass it as command line argument for ./show and it has to be by using pipes.

I have read any relevant question i could find but I cannot make it work.

So far I think I am directing the output into the pipe successfully but i dont know how to pass it to ./show. I ve been printing it just to verify it gets through the pipe.

```
        if(option == 2){

        getArgs(&A,args,directory,&size);

        pipe(fd);
        pid = fork();

        if(!pid){
            dup2(fd[1],STDOUT_FILENO); //output into pipe
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd[1]);

            com=args[0];
            for(i=1;i<(size-2);i++){
              com=concat(com," ");
              com=concat(com,args[i]);
            }

            readCommand(args,directory,com,(size-1));
            return 1;
        }

        close(fd[1]);

        int nbytes = read(fd[0], foo, sizeof(foo));
        printf("Output: (%.*s)\n", nbytes, foo);

    }
```

the exec happens inside readCommand so here it is

```
      void readCommand(char *args[10],char *directory,char *com, int i){

    if(execl(directory, args[i],args[i+1], NULL)==-1){
        execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", com, NULL);
        perror("execlp");
    }
    else{
        execl(directory, args[0],args[1],args[2],args[3],args[4], NULL); //max number of args=4
        perror("execlp");
    }
  }
```

I previously tried making it work with two forks, but then I m not sure i got the output redirected correctly, and it seems to be failing even harder. I can include that code too if its helpful.

Help is appreciated, my deadline is in a few hours...

Update: after reading the answer I updated the code

```
if(option == 2){

        getArgs(&A,args,directory,&size);

        pipe(fd);

        if (!fork()) {
            pipe(fd);

            if(!fork()) {

                dup2(fd[1], 1);
                close(fd[0]);
                close(fd[1]);

                execlp(args[0], args[0], NULL);
            }
            else {

                dup2(fd[0], 0);
                close(fd[0]);
                close(fd[1]);

                execlp(args[size-1], args[size-1], NULL);
            }
        }
        wait(NULL);
    }
```

now i get an empty line printed and then the prompt for a new command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fork two processes with a pipe between them. Your shell should not try to read from or write to the pipe.

Here's a complete example that hardcodes your pipeline to demonstrate how to set it up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
  char* producer="pwd";
  char* consumer="./show";
  int fds[2];

  printf("Going to run the equivalent of '%s | %s'\n", producer, consumer);
  // Create a child that will become the consumer
  if (!fork()) {
    pipe(fds);
    // Create another child to be the producer
    if(!fork()) {
      // Set up stdout to be the pipe
      dup2(fds[1], 1);
      close(fds[0]);
      close(fds[1]);
      // Execute the producer
      execlp(producer, producer, NULL);
    } else {
      // Set up stdin to be the pipe
      dup2(fds[0], 0);
      close(fds[0]);
      close(fds[1]);
      // Execute the consumer
      execlp(consumer, consumer, NULL);
    }
  }
  // Wait for the consumer to finish
  wait(NULL);
  printf("The pipeline is done, the \"shell\" is exiting\n");
}
```

Here's an implementation of `show`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Here's the data $0 read: $(cat)"
```

Here's the result from a real shell:

```
$ pwd
/tmp

$ pwd | ./show
Here's the data ./show read: /tmp
```

Here's the result when running this example:

```
$ gcc foo.c -o foo && ./foo
Going to run the equivalent of 'pwd | ./show'
Here's the data ./show read: /tmp
The pipeline is done, the "shell" is exiting
```

Comment: Using your code I improved my two-forks implementation...still doesnt work, would you take a look at the update?

Comment: The example works and you can test it, so it could be helpful to see why yours is different. For example, what does `args[0]` and `args[size-1]` contain?

Comment: the producer and consumer respectively, i had them printed out and they re okay. I tried to run your implementation of show but it doesnt compile, i get an error for #!, so i cant test it with that.

Comment: `show` is a shell script, it does not need compilation. You can just put it in a file called `show` and run `chmod +x show` to make it executable

Comment: If you would like to try to find out why, try including some more information. For example: "I tried copy-pasting `show` into a file, I successfully ran `chmod +x show`, but when I tried `pwd | ./show` from a terminal I get the error `bash: ./show: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`" instead of the expected message `Here's the data ./show read: /tmp`

Comment: here's what happens. If I do the same thing you do, `producer = "pwd"  consumer="./show"` , the program runs fine. But if I set `producer = args[0] consumer=args[size-1]` , it prints an empty line, then the prompt for a new command twice. I checked, and args[0], args[size-1] are indeed pwd and ./show respectively, I dont understand why it doesnt work.

Comment: Maybe `args[0]` is instead `"pwd "` with a trailing space? That wouldn't show up when you print it, and would cause the command to fail. You can either check it in your program, or you can run `strace -fe execve ./yourprogram` to show a debug dump of all attempted executions. It'll have lines like `[pid  3716] execve("/bin/pwd ", ["pwd "], 0x7fff197278d8 /* 31 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)` showing a trailing space